# Compiling all artifactory users into a list using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, artifactory

I am trying to use Python to retrieve all users in Artifactory and put them into a list.  Currently I can only find the solution to retrieving a single user via their username.  Is there a way to retrieve all users without needing to input usernames?

I imported the ArtifactoryPath package and I have tried to search usernames using Regex but with no luck.

Comment: This seems like it would be a better question for the Artifactory support team: https://jfrog.com/support/

Comment: Show us what you tried.
Getting all users should be quite easy using the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetUsers)

Comment: @DustinIngram I have already tried the support team - there is nothing that can solve my problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Get Users](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetUsers) REST API method to get a list of all users.
Please note that this API requires an admin user.